# How can I record the equivalent of Qualtrics "page submit" time in seconds using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I am trying to write javascript code that calculates the "page submit" time (time spent from start of view to next button click) in Qualtrics. I can't use the regular timed Qualtrics Question because I have other code that works with the next button, which does not work when I add a Qualtrics timing question to the page. (I've omitted that code from below just to make things simpler.)

I believe the problem is that I'm having trouble passing the start time from the Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload section to the Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnPageSubmit section.

I have two embedded data fields: StartHolder and TimeDiff, both set to 0.
I'm using the following code to try and calculate the time elapsed:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('StartHolder',new Date);
});

Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnPageSubmit(function() {
    var TimeDiff = new date() - Date.parse("${e://Field/StartHolder}");
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('TimeDiff',TimeDiff);
});
```

I think the problem is I'm not pulling the StartHolder variable back into my code properly, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set and pipe and an embedded variable on the same page.  You should set a JS variable as the start time then put your addOnPageSubmit function inside your addOnLoad function.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    var startHolder = new Date();
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnPageSubmit(function() {
       var TimeDiff = new Date() - startHolder;
       Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('TimeDiff',TimeDiff);
    });
});
```